# how to make circle in css divs?

Tags: html, css

code:

```
     <div className="color-container">
      <div className="inline" id="red"></div>
      <div className="inline" id="green"></div>
      <div className="inline" id="yellow"></div>
      <div className="inline" id="blue"></div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.color-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
.inline {
  display: inline;
}
#red {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
}
#yellow {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 0 50% 0 0;
}
#green {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green; 
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 0;
}
#blue {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 50%;
}
```

however nothing displays, even when i did display: inline on the child divs elements and on the parent I did 100px width and 200px height so the 2 divs goes to bottom?

Comment: what are you trying to make, could you attach any image of desired result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text overflow in circle div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624527/text-overflow-in-circle-div)

Comment: Can you share an expected output image. What you actually looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<div class="color-container">
      <div class="inline" id="red"></div><div class="inline" id="green"></div><div class="inline" id="blue"></div><div class="inline" id="yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <br><br> <!-- Other Way-->
    <div class="color-container">
      <div class="inline" id="red"></div><!--
      --><div class="inline" id="green"></div><!--
      --><div class="inline" id="blue"></div><!--
      --><div class="inline" id="yellow"></div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/krj1egLk/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```css
#left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0
}

#right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0
}

#left2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%
}

#right2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="left2"></div>
  <div id="right2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used className everywhere, this is wrong, it is just class, so you need to change this:

```
<div className="color-container">
```

to

```
<div class="color-container">
```

If you use this:

```
display: inline;
```

you can't set a width and height, because inline elements can't have that.

Instead you need to use display: inline-block:

```
.inline {
    display: inline;
}
```

However inline blocks have the problem that if you have spaces between them, they will add a gap between the divs, so need to remove all spaces from your html like this:

```
 <div class="color-container"><div class="inline" id="red"></div><div class="inline" id="green"></div><div class="inline" id="yellow"></div><div class="inline" id="blue"></div></div>
```

If you just want a circle with one color you could do this:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fiddle:

[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcf3ktdq/1/)

If i understood it correctly. This is my answer!

```css
    .color-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #red {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #yellow {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background-color: yellow;
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #green {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background-color: green; 
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #blue {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background-color: blue;
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="color-container">
      <div class="red" id="red"></div>
      <div class="yellow" id="green"></div>
      <div class="green" id="yellow"></div>
      <div class="blue" id="blue"></div>
 </div>
```